# Summation of a product

Tags: standard-deviation, approximation, sum

I need to calculate the following expression:

$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_k b_k$$

${a_k}$ and $b_k$ are real positive numbers. N and k are integers.

I know the average values of $a_k$ , defined as $\overline {a} = {\sum_{k=1}^N a_k \over N } $ and $b_k$ , defined as $\overline {b} = {\sum_{k=1}^N b_k \over N } $. I also know the standard deviation of $a_k$ and $b_k$, $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$.

If only knowing these quantities, I have to make some approximation, I would like to know how much error I am producing with that approximation. $N$ is relatively big.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to state that you know the vectors $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ up to permutation. (To maximize their inner product you put both sequences in ascending order; to minimize their inner product you put one in ascending order and the other in descending order.) But I'm not sure that's what you're saying, because if you *do* have this kind of information then you can easily compute both the means and the SDs, yet you specifically remark that you have the means and yet cannot find the SDs.  Could you please edit the question to clarify exactly what information you really have?

Comment: I think I can not put the sequences ascending or descending, because although I know for instance 80% of $a_k$ have the same vale of $a_1$, still I don't know the value of $a_1$. Do you think I can calculate SD with this condition?

Comment: Given that you do not know the values of the $a_k$ nor of the $b_k,$ you will have to find extreme values that are consistent with what you do know. Your information includes the mean and the fact that the $a_k$ are non-negative, but you haven't given us any information about the possible values of the $b_k$ nor about the possible upper bounds on the $a_k$: both of these are essential for bounding the inner product.

Comment: My experimental data are sparse, but I might be able to find the standard deviation from the error bars of the experiments. So, I will change the question to see how this expression could be calculated knowing also the SDs. The reply to that would help me too.